# How fast does $f_n = \sin f_{n-1}$ approach zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence $f(n) = \sin(\sin(\sin(......(1)......)))$ approaches zero like $\sqrt{3/n}$, as has been asked and answered here a few times.

So $f(n)$ would get below $1/n$ after $3n^2$ steps, but it seems to get there about $\ln n$ steps earlier: 0.1 after 295, 0.01 after 29992, 0.001 after 2999989 steps.

Is that numerical roundoff error or not?

Comment: What is your measurement of the speed of convergence?

Comment: I think we should attempt to characterize the speed of convergence by some other simpler functions. For example, show that f(n) ~ g(n) as n tends to inf, where g(n) is easier to work with than sin(sin(sin... (1.. )

Comment: this may help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45283/lim-n-to-infty-sin-sin-sin-n

Comment: This question has been asked before. [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276135/calculating-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-sin-sin-sinx/276139) [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/convergence-of-sqrtnx-n-where-x-n1-sinx-n) [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45283/lim-n-to-infty-sin-sin-sin-n).

Comment: Anyway, the answer is that $f(n) \sim \sqrt{3/n}$, and also the stronger result that $f(n) < \sqrt{3/n}$.

Comment: Thankyou; how do you remember 100000 questions ago?  It seems to take around $\log(n)$ steps fewer than $n^2/3$ to reach $1/n$.  Is that numerical error or not?

Comment: Banach fixed-point theorem might help

Answer (score 1):

Here is an incomplete answer which may still satisfy you: By a Taylor series approximation, when $x$ is small,
$$\sin x = x - \frac {x^2} 2 + O(x^3)\\
\sin \sin x = \sin x - \frac { (\sin x)^2 } 2 + O((\sin x)^3) = x - x^2 + O(x^3) \\
\sin \sin \sin x = x - x^2 - \frac { (x - x^2)^2 } 2 + O(x^3) = x - \frac 3 2 x^2 + O(x^3)
$$
and so on... One could show by induction that
$$\underbrace {\sin \sin \ldots \sin }_{n}\ x=x-\frac n 2 x^2 + O(x^3)$$
The constant hidden in the $O$-notation depends on $n$ of course, so this cannot be used to give you precise answers, but you can get an order of magnitude.

For example, how many sines does one need to take to get from $x = \epsilon$ to $x = \frac \epsilon 2$ when $\epsilon$ is small? Let's say $\epsilon - \frac n 2 \epsilon^2 \approx \frac \epsilon 2$; then you need $n \approx \frac 1 \epsilon$ steps.