# How do I solve this limit: $ \lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt{n}\sin(\sin(\sin ... (\sin (1))...)) $

Tags: limits

I have been strugling a lot to solve this question, but couldn't figure out where to start.

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty } \sqrt{n} . \underbrace {\sin(\sin(\sin ... (\sin (1))...))}_{n...times..} $$

I think maybe I should assume the part inside brackets as $y$.

But what next??

Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276135/calculating-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-sin-sin-sinx?rq=1

Comment: Presumably $x$ and $n$ are somehow related...

Comment: It should be $n \to +\infty $ instead of $x \to +\infty $, no?

Comment: @IvoTerek yes, sorry.

Comment: @math110 I saw that link but didn't understand the solution as it involves range, domain etc. and more concerned with analysis. Can I xpect a bit easier solution? something more basic?