# Volume in cone segment bent from rectangle.

Tags: differential-geometry, recreational-mathematics

A flexible rectangle sheet size $(a,b),a>b $ is folded half  along side $a$ and glued to make a circular cone cut segment of vertex angle $60^{\circ}$ as shown with three edges $(b,a,b).$

( $60^{\circ}$ choice for cone apex angle deformation arises due to maximum volume created by internal pressure at $90^{\circ}$ corner obtained by maintaining second order continuity along a line perpendicular to glue line.)

After bending distorted edges $(a,b)$ are curved/mapped as conical helices with Clairaut minimal radii nearer to cone vertex as $ (r_a,r_b)= (a/4,b).$ The cone surface is a single boat shaped nappe.

Calculate bent area to verify $A= ab $ conserved due to isometry.

Calculate volume enclosed by parallel displacement of edge $AB$ (skew perpendicular to cone axis) along the helices.

It refers to Jack D'Aurizio [A4 paper sheet bent volume](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855975/what-is-the-maximum-volume-that-can-be-contained-by-a-sheet-of-paper) problem with two nappes.

[image: Isometric Bending of Sheet to Cone]

Comment: Are you asking for the volume of the convex hull of this surface?

Comment: Yes, if $AB$ is a rubber band then it is the concept of convex hull.  (Jack D'Aurizio's  problem is different, it asks for holding maximum water at an inclination of cone/ object  that may need to be defined).  in this case no edges are in a horizontal plane.

Comment: I don't think the resulting solid is convex, because the segment joining the midpoint of $AB$ with the midpoint $C$ or $C'$ of either curve lays outside the solid. The convex hull is simply the solid having for boundaries the cone and planes $ABC$ and $ABC'$.

Comment: I was imagining lines parallel to $AB$ contacting and sliding along both helices,so that surface has an area $=ab$

Comment: Why should lines parallel to $AB$ sweep an area $ab$?

Comment: Thanks for nice sketch. I meant not the new swept area but the original brown conical surface itself that  you sketched having  area $A=ab$ conserved by isometry i.e. by ,bending to a  cone.

Answer (score 4):

You can see below a diagram of the solid, made with GeoGebra. Green surface $ABC$ is described by $AB$ sliding along the border: it is apparent from the diagram that segment $CM$ lies over the surface, hence the solid is not convex.

[image]

The equation for the lateral surface (orange) can be obtained by noticing that a generic point $P$ on the sheet of paper, having distance $r$ from the midpoint $V$ of the folded side and forming an angle $\angle CVP=\theta$, gets mapped to point 
$$
P'=\left({1\over2}r\cos2\theta,\ {1\over2}r\sin2\theta,\ {\sqrt3\over2}r \right)
$$

of the cone, if we take its axis along $z$ and $V$ as origin.

[image]

Comment: You answer was pretty useful . May i see the GeoGebra file if you dont mind ? Intelligenti Pauca

Comment: Hello @ProblemDestroyer. I'm afraid I don't have that file anymore. Anyway, it shouldn't be too difficult to reproduce it: I may give a try to it, when I have some spare time.

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer Sorry for the delay, I finally reconstructed the GeoGebra file, here it is: https://www.geogebra.org/m/qdgtrggu

Comment: Beautiful thanks