# Using (rigid) Origami moves only, what is the maximum volume that can be enclosed by a square piece of paper?

Tags: geometry, optimization, recreational-mathematics, volume, origami

### Motivation:

This is inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855975/what-is-the-maximum-volume-that-can-be-contained-by-a-sheet-of-paper).

### The Question:

> What is the maximum volume that can be enclosed by folding a square piece of paper (with side length $\ell$) using only (rigid) Origami moves?

### Thoughts:

I found [this](http://www.cutoutfoldup.com/924-maximum-volume-from-a-square-net.php), but it's not very helpful because it doesn't give a specific volume and I can't find the paper it references.

It's not a question I think I can answer myself. I have no formal training in Origami and know very little about it.

I'm guessing the shape is just a cube but I'm not sure how to prove that.

Please help :)

Comment: It seems you want a closed (convex?) polyhedron whereas the linked question concerns an open "dish". If so, see Alexander, Dyson, and O'Rourke, "[The Foldings of a Square to Convex Polyhedra](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/Papers/sq.pdf), 2002.

Comment: Well, *a priori*, at least, there's nothing to say that the shape is convex. But thank you :)

Comment: The ref it pointed to is a book (I've a hard copy of that). In the book, it say the volume is about $0.056$ which is about $60$% of the volume of a unit-area sphere.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0521857570/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_e9B8BbEHDYZCK) the book you mean, @achillehui?

Comment: yes, it is that book.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. It's assuming $\ell=1$, right, @achillehui ?

Comment: that result is for a unit square. i.e. $\ell = 1$.

Comment: The same result is included in the paper I linked to (Joseph O'Rourke is a coauthor of both), and the paper is freely available via O'Rourke's webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to close the question, here is a community wiki answer from the comments.

> The ref it pointed to is a book (I've a hard copy of that). In the book, it say the volume is about $0.056$ which is about $60\%$ of the volume of a unit-area sphere.

[This is by achille hui, Nov 18 at 19:31.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3003930/using-rigid-origami-moves-only-what-is-the-maximum-volume-that-can-be-enclose/3011149#comment6196188_3003930)

Comment: @achillehui, I'll leave this here until you post the answer yourself.

Comment: I won't post any answer. Joseph O'Rourke is a user on math.SE. If he ever see this question, he can provide an answer with much more details...

Comment: Well, until that day, @achillehui, this answer should suffice.

Comment: In fact, here's a tag for @JosephO'Rouke. I hope he doesn't mind this comment $\ddot\smile$.

Comment: Tagging a general user won't work. The system will only notify the user if he/she has interacted with a page before.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you, @achillehui :)